# Striling numbers of the first kind $S(m,m-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, stirling-numbers

> I want to derive a formula for $S(m,m-1)$ where $S(m,n)$ is the number
>   of ways to seat $m$ people at $n$ circular tables with at least one
>   person at each table, The arrangements at any one table are not
>   distinguished if one can be rotated into another and the ordering of
>   the tables is insignificant.

So the way I think about it is breaking this into cases.

When $m$ people are seated on $m-1$ tables so that each of the tables contain at least $1$ person. There can be

**Case 1**

Two people are seated on one table and the remaining $m-2$ people are seated on $m-2$ tables, so that each of these $m-2$ tables have one person each. Now there are ${m \choose 2}$ ways to choose these two people but then how many ways for this case in total ? is it just ${m \choose 2}$ because we don't really care about the ordering of the tables. We just care about the two people who are seating in that table right ?

But then I can't really think of any other cases. Is it true that I only have one case here ?

So If would to make a guess, I would just say $$m \choose 2$$

Comment: Yes, both the result and the reasoning are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Brian commented, both the result and the reasoning are correct.